# Delete and restore postgress database in sikuli

Tags: postgresql, sikuli-ide

I have used below code to delete postgress database. My issue is I am unable to find query which would restore database. Please provide your assistance. thank you!!

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import sys
from sikuli import *
from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC
load("C:\\Test\\SikuliX\\postgresql-9.4.1207.jre6")

connection2 = zxJDBC.connect('jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/?stringtype=unspecified', 'postgres', 'pswd@123', 'org.postgresql.Driver')
connection2.autocommit = True
curs = connection2.cursor()

curs.execute('DROP DATABASE  IF EXISTS  sampledb')

curs.execute( < I need query to restore database>)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "command" to restore a postgresql database. Usually a backup consists of a very large bunch of commands that piece by piece create a database that is mostly identical to what you have backupped before. Your only possibility is to use the shell command pg_restore.

Oh, and your question has nothing to do with sikuli-ide. The problem is programming language agnostic.

Comment: Yes it's true it has nothing to do with sikuli ide but i am unable to find solution. Can you please show an example how do I use pg_restore in sikuli ide?

Comment: Sikuli is just an IDE! Your coding seems to be done in eithe Python, Ruby or JavaScript, and your Code looks like python. Please refer to the Python documentation on how to call a shell command, and read the PostgreSQL documentation on how to use pg_restore specifically.

Comment: Yes, I know sikuli is just an IDE and my coding is done in python. My problem is I cant get pg_restore or psql e.g (psql -d postgres -U postgres -f D:\DataBasebakcup\sample_backup) run successfully in sikuli IDE. I have gone through python documentation and postSQL documentation but didnt get any success and hence asked for help. If you know, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found workaround for this, instead of restore we can copy the database
curs.execute('CREATE DATABASE [newdb] WITH TEMPLATE [originaldb] OWNER dbuser')